# Is "int2rgb" an OK method name?

Tags: java

All colors can be represented by an `int`, and often you want to get the individual red, green and blue values from that `int`.

I have a method `int2rgb` (and another called `rgb2int`) that does this. Is this a clear/good name?

```
public static int[] int2rgb(final int color) {
    return new int[] { (color >> 16) & 0xFF, (color >> 8) & 0xFF, color & 0xFF };
}

public static int rgb2int(final int red, final int green, final int blue) {
    return (red << 16) + (green << 8) + blue;
}

public static int rgb2int(final int[] color) {
    return (color[0] << 16) + (color[1] << 8) + color[2];
}
```

And in case you are interested, the rest of the class is [here](https://bitbucket.org/alienmegacorp/alien-megacorp-utils/src/f613eae008be/src/com/alienmegacorp/utils/ColorUtils.java).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as naming is concerned: Using 2 instead of `to` is pretty much a no-no - "to" is spelled out everywhere in the Java standard library. Further Java's naming convention is to capitalize every word, but the first in method names - except for acronyms which are all-caps no matter where they appear in the name. So the methods should be called `intToRGB` and `RGBtoInt` (`to` is lower case because it directly follows an acronym - compare for example `Color.RGBtoHSB` in the java standard library).

In regards to the code: I'd recommend representing your colors as `Color` objects rather than 3-element arrays. If you choose to do that, you don't have to define any of your methods, because that functionality already exists in the `Color` class.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236807/java-naming-convention-with-acronyms for a discussion about acronyms naming (I would personnly use `intToRgb` and `rgbToInt`)

Answer (score 1):

Make a RGB class with properties Red, Green and Blue and add a static `FromInt()` method, or a `RGB(int color)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Capitalization:

I would use something in the form `rgbToInt` or `intToRgb`. I know, Javadoc tells that acronyms should be capitalized, but that leads to some weird results (v.g., `RGB rGBVariable;`)

1) Joel Spolsky recommends to use "form" instead of "to", so code is easier to read. 
Compare

```
Rgb rgbVariable = intToRgb(intVariable); // mix of `rgb` an `int` in the line
```

to

```
Rgb rgbVariable = rgbFromInt(intVariable); // `rgb` to the right, `int` to the left; mistakes are easier to spot
```

More info here http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html